# How to fix issue with ToggleButton/Rectangle & Grid Rowspan

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a button in my grid that will increase the Rowspan of the grid when I click it. I have created a Rectangle to place behind the ToggleButton for a better look when hovering. The rowspan switches perfectly when clicking the image/ToggleButton. But only will work for the rectangle if I click it before the ToggleButton. After I click the button once, the Rectangle click will no longer work.

```xml
<Grid ShowGridLines="False" Background="#282828">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="68" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="1000">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#1c1c1c" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#1c1c1c" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>

        <Rectangle x:Name="MenuButton" MouseEnter="Menu_Mouse_Enter" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" MouseLeave="Menu_Mouse_Leave" MouseDown="Menu_Button_Click">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#1c1c1c" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#1c1c1c" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>

        <ToggleButton x:Name="MenuToggleButton" MouseEnter="Menu_Mouse_Enter" MouseLeave="Menu_Mouse_Leave" Click="Menu_Button_Click" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="32" Width="32">
            <ToggleButton.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Image Width="32" Height="32" Source="Resources/menu.png" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ToggleButton.Template>
        </ToggleButton>
    </Grid>
```

```cs
public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Title = "Youtube+ | #1 Youtube Client";
            this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            this.Height = 768;
            this.Width = 1024;
        }

        private void Menu_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var element = (UIElement) MenuButton;
            if (MenuToggleButton.IsChecked == true)
            {
                Grid.SetRowSpan(element, 1);

            }
            else
            {
                Grid.SetRowSpan(element, 1000);

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Sent");
        }

        private void Menu_Mouse_Leave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var element = (UIElement) e.Source;

            var c = Grid.GetColumn(element);
            var r = Grid.GetRow(element);
            if (c == 0 || r == 0)
            {
                Brush darker = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(28,28,28));
                MenuButton.Fill = darker;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
            Console.WriteLine(r);

        }

        private void Menu_Mouse_Enter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var element = (UIElement) e.Source;

            var c = Grid.GetColumn(element);
            var r = Grid.GetRow(element);
            if (c == 0 && r == 0)
            {
                Brush dark = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(40,40,40));
                MenuButton.Fill = dark;
            }
        }
    }
```

This should be the part that makes it work, right?

```cs
private void Menu_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var element = (UIElement) MenuButton;
            if (MenuToggleButton.IsChecked == true)
            {
                Grid.SetRowSpan(element, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                Grid.SetRowSpan(element, 1000);

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Sent");
        }
```

Also worth nothing that my Console.WriteLine("Sent"); doesn't show in console.

Comment: What exactly is it that doesn't work as you expect? How do you reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but instead of using the rectangle for expanding when you hover it, the best bet would be to edit the Style and Controltemplate of Toggle button. Once you open up togglebutton's template, change the one with the look and feel you want. You can also create some TemplateBinding or custom control where you can hook up your properties while databinding or elementbinding.

I hope I do make sense here.